# How to know if the Spinner is increasing in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, spinner

I would like to know if there is any method to know when the `Spinner` is increased.

The ideal would be to know the moment in which the `Spinner` increases

Comment: I've been researching about methods, but I haven´t found one that works for what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [`ChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) to the `value` property of the `Spinner` which will be notified of changes. Since the old and the new values are both passed to the `changed` method, it allows you to find out, if the value was increased or decreased:

```
Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(0, 100, 0);
spinner.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (oldValue < newValue) {
        System.out.println("value increased");
    }
});
```

In the handler you could also retrieve the time, e.g. by using `System.currentTimeMillis` if this is necessary.

Comment: Great, works great, just what I was looking for, thank you